# DHL Real Time Shipping calculator

Tags: api, shopify

Is this possible to have DHL's api implemented into Shopify?

We are assuming you would need a custom UI inside Shopify as well.

Not sure why this feature is not offered as DHL has the best rates for international shipping.

Let us know if anyone is up to develop this and what cost would be.

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an App that queries DHL for shipping rates. You can hook that up on the cart. That way your customers would know what DHL charges based on whatever it is you cooked up for your products. Weight based estimates differ from dimensional ones.

Assuming you got decent estimates on shipping you'd be then wanting to hook up shipping rates inside your Shopify to use DHL. That is the rub there. If you cannot hook up to DHL inside Shopify to setup rates, there is not much you can do inside checkout.

Perhaps Shopify has hooks now so a shop can call in their own shipping rates? Ask them.

Answer (score 0):

StarShipIt have a real time calculator for Shopify and DHL, I suggest getting in contact with them.

Answer (score -1):

Shopify has not provided carrier calculated shipping for DHL. Since this issue has been raised since 2008, I suspect they will not, at least for the near future. Personally, I have emailed tech support and have yet to receive a clear answer. If this is a necessity for your site, you may have to try another solution.